# Terragrunt with Hashicorp Vault does not initialise & apply the vault dependency from root folder,need to exclusively initialise Vault from sub folder

Tags: azure, terraform, vault, terragrunt

I am new to terraform and terragrunt. I am using Vault to store Azure Service Principal and provisioning infra using terragrunt. I am unable to initialize and apply the vault dependency from root folder, need to exclusively initialize Vault from its sub folder.

Modules:
Resource Group, VM, VNET and Vault.

RG depends on Vault, VNet depends on RG, and VM depends on RG and VNet.

**My repo looks like this:**
.[image: Terragrunt repo structure]

When I run terragrunt init in the root level with terragrunt.hcl file , it gets stuck in **initialising state** because it does not receive vault module outputs. But when I go to Vault-tf folder and do terragrunt init and terragrunt apply, it fetches the vault secrets properly and post this when I run terragrunt init and terragrunt apply at root level , it works fine and creates the azure resources successfully.

**My root terragrunt.hcl file looks like this:**

```
dependency "credentials" {
config_path = "/root/terragrunt-new/BaseConfig/Vault-tf"

mock_outputs = {
tenant_id = "temp-tenant-id"
client_id = "temp-client-id"
client_secret = "temp-secret-id"
subscription_id = "temp-subscription-id"
}
}

terraform {
source = "git::https://git link to modules//"

extra_arguments "force_subscription" {
    commands = [
    "init",
    "apply",
    "destroy",
    "refresh",
    "import",
    "plan",
    "taint",
    "untaint"
    ]
env_vars = {
     ARM_TENANT_ID     = dependency.credentials.outputs.tenant_id
     ARM_CLIENT_ID     = dependency.credentials.outputs.client_id
     ARM_CLIENT_SECRET = dependency.credentials.outputs.client_secret
     ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID = dependency.credentials.outputs.subscription_id
    }
}
}

inputs = {
prefix = "terragrunt-nbux"
location = "centralus"
}

locals {
subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxx-cc3e-4014-a891-xxxxxxxxxx"
}

generate "versions" {
path = "versions_override.tf"
if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
contents = <<EOF
terraform {
required_providers {
azurerm = {
source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
version = "3.9.0"
}
vault = {
source = "hashicorp/vault"
version = "3.7.0"
}
}
}

provider "vault" {
   address = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8200"
   skip_tls_verify = true
   token = "hvs.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}
EOF
}

remote_state {
backend = "azurerm"
config = {
subscription_id = "${local.subscription_id}"
key = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
resource_group_name = "rg-terragrunt-vault"
storage_account_name = "terragruntnbuxstorage"
container_name = "base-config-tfstate"
}
generate = {
path = "backend.tf"
if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
}
}
```

**And my Vault-tf folder's terragrunt.hcl file looks like this**

```
terraform {
  source = "git::https:path/terragrunt-new//Modules/Vault"
}

generate "versions" {
  path      = "versions_override.tf"
  if_exists = "overwrite_terragrunt"
  contents  = <<EOF
    terraform {
      required_providers {
      
        vault = {
          source = "hashicorp/vault"
          version = "3.7.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "vault" {
       address = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8200"
       skip_tls_verify = true
       token = "hvs.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxI"
    }
EOF
}
```

Comment: This should be possible. Can you try it with direct TF instead of the terragrunt wrapper?

Comment: But I need to take care of the dependency structure.

Comment: seem like you forgot to use `include` block in the child `terragrunt.hcl`
and seem like its inteded to run it from child terragrunt.hcl as root terragrunt.hcl usually to centralized common config

Comment: @gumelaragum, I added below block in the vault .hcl file: 
`include "root" {
  path   = find_in_parent_folders()
  expose = true
}`

But it throws error as :
`ERRO[0000] Found a dependency cycle between modules: /root/terragrunt-new/BaseConfig/terragrunt.hcl -> /root/terragrunt-new/BaseConfig/Vault-tf/terragrunt.hcl -> /root/terragrunt-new/BaseConfig/Vault-tf/terragrunt.hcl 
ERRO[0000] Unable to determine underlying exit code, so Terragrunt will exit with error code 1 `